# Why my firebase update function is not always working?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Im trying to figuring out why my firebase funtion for cheat is always creating but when like open the chat where it call create function immediately send a message the message will not be saved, because my function is not ready so how can I sole this?.
Heres my function .

```
export const onConversationCreated = functions.firestore.
    document("Conversations/{conversationID}").onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const data = snapshot.data();
      const conversationID = context.params.conversationID;
      if (data) {
        const members = data.members;
        for (let index = 0; index < members.length; index++) {
          const uid = members[index];
          const remainingUserIDs = members.filter((u: string) => u !== uid);
          remainingUserIDs.forEach((m: string) => {
            return admin.firestore().
                collection("profile").doc(m).get().then((_doc) => {
                  const userData = _doc.data();
                  if (userData) {
                    return admin.firestore().collection("profile")
                        .doc(uid).collection("Conversations").doc(m).create({
                          "conversationID": conversationID,
                          "url": userData.url,
                          "name": userData.username,
                          "unseenCount": 0,
                        });
                  }
                  return null;
                }).catch(() => {
                  return null;
                });
          });
        }
      }
      return null;
    });


export const onConversationUpdated = functions.firestore
    .document("Conversations/{conversationID}").onUpdate((change, context) => {
      const data = change?.after.data();
      if (data) {
        const members = data.members;
        const lastMessage = data.messages[data.messages.length - 1];
        for (let index = 0; index < members.length; index++) {
          const uid = members[index];
          const remainingUserIDs = members.filter((u: string) => u !== uid);
          remainingUserIDs.forEach((u: string) => {
            return admin.firestore().collection("meinprofilsettings")
                .doc(uid).collection("Conversation").doc(u).update({
                  "lastMessage": lastMessage.message,
                  "timestamp": lastMessage.timestamp,
                  "type": lastMessage.type,
                  "lastmessageuid": lastMessage.senderID,
                  "unseenCount": admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
                });
          });
        }
      }
      return null;
    });
```

So again creating is correct working. its just need some time . And when I immediately when calling create function write a message and send it this message will not be saved until the create function is finished then I have to send again the message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Es9F.png)

Comment: you can make function as `Future` and then apply `whenComplete()` on it to process only when the function is executed.  or `await` for your function before making new call

Comment: Like how ? Can you maybe edit my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your bug is that you don't await the execution of your `async` task correctly. Unfortunately the `forEach` doesn't support `async` so we need to revrite your code to something like this:

```js
export const onConversationCreated = functions.firestore
  .document("Conversations/{conversationID}")
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const data = snapshot.data();
    const promises: Promise<any>[] = [];
    const conversationID = context.params.conversationID;
    if (data) {
      const members = data.members;

      for (let index = 0; index < members.length; index++) {
        const uid = members[index];
        const remainingUserIDs = members.filter((u: string) => u !== uid);

        remainingUserIDs.forEach((m: string) => {
          promises.push(
            admin
              .firestore()
              .collection("profile")
              .doc(m)
              .get()
              .then((_doc) => {
                const userData = _doc.data();
                if (userData) {
                  return admin
                    .firestore()
                    .collection("profile")
                    .doc(uid)
                    .collection("Conversations")
                    .doc(m)
                    .create({
                      conversationID: conversationID,
                      url: userData.url,
                      name: userData.username,
                      unseenCount: 0,
                    });
                }
                return null;
              })
          );
        });
      }
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
  });

export const onConversationUpdated = functions.firestore
  .document("Conversations/{conversationID}")
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const data = change?.after.data();
    const promises: Promise<any>[] = [];
    if (data) {
      const members = data.members;

      const lastMessage = data.messages[data.messages.length - 1];
      for (let index = 0; index < members.length; index++) {
        const uid = members[index];
        const remainingUserIDs = members.filter((u: string) => u !== uid);
        remainingUserIDs.forEach((u: string) => {
          promises.push(
            admin
              .firestore()
              .collection("meinprofilsettings")
              .doc(uid)
              .collection("Conversation")
              .doc(u)
              .update({
                lastMessage: lastMessage.message,
                timestamp: lastMessage.timestamp,
                type: lastMessage.type,
                lastmessageuid: lastMessage.senderID,
                unseenCount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
              })
          );
        });
      }
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
  });
```

We use `Promise.all()` to even run all your `async` tasks in parallel to finish the function faster and save on execution time.

Comment: Did you mean Promise because it says  Cannot find name 'promises'.Did you mean 'Promise'? haha

Comment: Sorry the `const promises = []` was in the condition. I updated the code. Can you pls try it again.

Comment: Did you copy the whole code again? `promises` is a constand we define in the code. Can't imagine tha it can't be found before we define it when the function starts. Can you give me the whole error message.

Comment: I updated a picture is you can see how it looks

Comment: Ah that is a Typescript thing ;) I have changed the answer again.